# How to keep track of original destination address in transparent proxy

Tags: sockets, proxy, iptables

I'm trying to implement a transparent proxy in C++ which will monitor outgoing tcp connections with certain ports and forward or block them as needed.

I have defined a rule to forward call destined to port 9002 to localhost port 9001 as:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 9002 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:9001
```

now when client tries to connect to server (which is also running in same host) with

```
./client 127.0.0.1 9002
```

the call is forwarded to port 9001 and the application listening on port 9001 gets the connection properly. My question is how the application running on port 9001 can know that this call needs to be sent to its **original destination** `127.0.0.1:9002` after it's done with it? Tried calling getsockname on accepted socket as in application listening on port `9001`:

```
struct sockaddr_in sockaddr;
socklen_t len = sizeof(sockaddr);
getsockname(socketfd, (struct sockaddr *) &sockaddr, &len);
```

but this return `127.0.0.1:44853` which is not what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this still helps you after almost a year...
I understand you are on Linux and using NAT.
I believe you can just use getsockopt with SO_ORIGINAL_DST...